# Colored texture applies grey when applied to object in unity

Tags: texturing, uv, unity

I created a UV map of my 3d model and painted it and saved the image as a png file. It imported into unity fine, and the texture is even colored in the thumbnail but when I apply it to the object it's entirely grey and doesn't show the green/grey color it's supposed to be. I'm new to blender and I'm not sure what I did wrong, and i'm not sure if this is an error I've done within blender or an error within unity. Here is a screen shot of unity the texture is highlighted in the assets, and the color my object is is the color it produces instead of the green/grey.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: Most likely your landscape mesh doesn't have the correct UVs on the first UV channel or the texture is not yet assigned to the material that the object has in Unity.